# Clean way to truncate QueryString from a relative Uri c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Given a URI like:

```
/path/page/?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

As it would be generated by using:

```
Url.Action("page","path", new { param1 = "value", param2 = "value2" })
```

What would be the cleanest way to strip the query string so it would result in `/path/page/`?

After searching in SO specifically and a more wide Google search, the best answer I found was to create a Uri object and use `uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)` which I already know and use for absolute URIs.

Problem is, this will not work for relative URIs, and both doing

```
Uri uri = new Uri(new Uri("http://www.fakesite.com"), myRelativeUri)
string cleanUri = uri.AbsolutePath
```

and

```
string cleanUri = myRelativeUri.Substring(0, myRelativeUri.IndexOf('?'))
```

look sloppy.

Comment: Another alternative `string cleanUri = myRelativeUri.Split('?')[0];`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use `string clearnUri = myRelativeUri.Split('?')[0];`

It's about as clean as you're going to get.

Comment: the simplest :P

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like `Substring` then you can use `String.Remove` like:

```
string cleanUri = myRelativeUri.Remove(myRelativeUri.IndexOf('?'));
```

But make sure you check for existence of the question mark first.

```
if (myRelativeUri.Contains('?'))
    cleanUri = myRelativeUri.Remove(myRelativeUri.IndexOf('?'));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in .Net Framework to help you with that...

I'd vote for string manipulation if you prefer inline code - trick with making Uri absolute does not work for schema-less relative urls like `"//sample.com/file?query"`.